# JSR303 validations using Database connection

Tags: database, bean-validation

General question:

This is using JSR303 bean validation, Hibernate reference implementation.

Suppose I have a set of custom validations; some of them require a database connection (Note: we are not using Hibernate for DB element mapping so unfortunately this is not an option).  For example, I might want to validate a foriegn key before persistance.

Anyway, I cannot see a way at the moment of passing a DB connection into the Validator.validate(obj) method, so as to make it available to the validation implementations. It's important that this connection be the same one as is in use in the calling code, for session consistency reasons.

Any ideas..?  All I really need is a way to get a runtime value of any kind into the validator implementation.

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom [ConstraintValidatorFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e2697) to instantiate and configure `ConstraintValidator` objects. This factory could pass the required dependencies such as a database connection to the created constraint validators.

If you're using CDI for wiring your application, you might be interested in [Seam Validation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/latest/reference/en-US/html/validation-dependency-injection.html#d0e11441) (disclaimer: I'm the author), which provides dependency injection for validators based on CDI. If you're using the Spring Framework, you can also [make use](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-constraints) of dependency injection within constraint validator implementations.